# JS - onkeypress keeps appending text to end

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Angular app i have an input field with `onkeypress` which i use to remove any commas if entered:

```
<input name="option" ng-model="main.optionToAdd" 
   onkeypress="this.value = this.value.replace(/,/g, '')"
</>
```

However the issue I'm facing is if after enter something in the field then go to the middle (either click or use arrow keys) then type something it always appends to end.

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` are your friends. read them, figure out where they are after your replacement and reapply them. magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are changing/reassigning the value of the textbox, hence the cursor comes at end. 
Instead of reassigning the value of textbox try to capture the pressed key using **onkeydown** event and prevent the keypress if it is **comma** (ASCII code 188).

```
<input name="option" onkeydown="return event.which==188?false:true;">
```